# reload css in browser without refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have situation where I have to make some changes on css file and reload it for this i have done this but browser need to refresh for reflect those changes please help

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "handlers/load-css-file.ashx",
    data: { colorCode: colorCode, defaultColor:   defaultColor,currentCss:currentCss },
    dataType: 'text',
    async: false,
    success: function () {
        _edSite.theme = currentCss;
        edLoadCss(_workUrl + _edSite.theme);
    },
    error: function () {
        alert("Please try after some time.");
    }
 });

 //loading css file on the website
 function edLoadCss(href) {
    var cssLink = $("<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='" + href +  "'>");
    $("head").append(cssLink);
 };
```

I don't want to reload browser for this.

Comment: Does the browser really need to refresh? It's only the CSS you need to reload, so just make sure that it has not been cached.

Comment: I think this is happening because of cache but i don't have an idea how to clean it.

Comment: thanks but not working for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "handlers/load-css-file.ashx",
    data: { colorCode: colorCode, defaultColor:   defaultColor,currentCss:currentCss },
    dataType: 'text',
    async: false,
    success: function () {
        _edSite.theme = currentCss;
        edLoadCss(_workUrl + _edSite.theme);
    },
    error: function () {
        alert("Please try after some time.");
    }
 });

 //loading css file on the website
 function edLoadCss(href) {
    var d = new Date();
    $("link [rel=stylesheet]").attr("href", href + "?" + d.getTime());
 };
```

Comment: @user3779305 have you an  error? you could test `Date().d.getTime()` on your own code